# Oracle 12c - how to create new partitions automatically with list partitions

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have in Oracle 12c a 'list' partitioned table and sub-partitions also on the same table as a 'list' partitions. Both of columns that these partitions use are varchar types.

How to create new partitions automatically (when new value comes) based on these 2 partitions? (without hardcoding all partition names ahead of time)

Thanks.

Comment: Search here. The answer contains a link to help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191780/dynamic-table-partitioning-in-oracle

Comment: Oracle Database 12c (12cR2) comes with AUTOLIST partitioning. You can google to learn more about it. But I am not sure when it will be available for everyone.

Comment: How about in '12.1.0.2.0' version? (R1) Is it possible to do autolist (or somehow auto generate partitions) based on 'varchar' column?

Answer (score 0):

In the question there was mention of subpartitions on the table. For the record, Oracle doesn't support interval partitioning at the subparition level. This is true as of release 19.1 and prior. See the SQL Reference Guide for a list of restrictions on interval partitioning. It's under the chapter called Create Table.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6